# Angle formed between two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Given the vectors $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ $\in$ $\Bbb{R}^3$ find the values (if exists) of $k$ $\in$ $\Bbb{R}$ so the angle between $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ equals to $\pi$ radians.

**$\vec{a}$ = (2, -2, 0)**, **$\vec{b}$ = (-1, 0, 1)** and **$\vec{c}$ = k$\vec{a}$ + $\vec{b}$**.

I tried with this equation $\cos \left(\alpha \right)=\frac{\vec{b}\cdot \vec{c}}{\left|\vec{b}\right|\left|\vec{c}\right|}$ replacing $\alpha$ for $\pi$ and obtained $k = 0$ which doesn't seem correct.

Any hint would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that if the angle between two vectors is $\pi$ then the vectors must be anti-parallel

Comment: Are you sure the expression for $ \ \overrightarrow{c} \ $ is stated correctly?  Since $ \ \overrightarrow{a} \ $ has a $ \ y-$ component which is non-zero, there is no scalar multiplier other than zero that can eliminate it in order to make $ \ \overrightarrow{c} \ $ parallel _or_ anti-parallel to $ \ \overrightarrow{b} \ \ . $  And as the expression stands now, $ \ k = 0 \ $ makes $ \ \overrightarrow{c} = \overrightarrow{b} \ \ . $